# how do I add a javascript to a single node in drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, drupal

How do I add a specific javascript to a specific node in drupal 7?
Right now i add my .js javascript via the "javascript librairies" module. But this adds the .js to all nodes.
I want to have myjavascript1.js enabled for node 1 and myjavascript2.je available for node 2?

Is there a way to acheive that? DO I have to make my own module?

Comment: Use the [`hook_node_view_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) hook, and call [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to include your JS. Might want to take care not to add the same JS twice in case multiple nodes using the same JS are rendered on one page. (Also: there's a [separate StackExchange for Drupal questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/). )

Answer (score 1):

Create `node--525.tpl.php` a separate template file, replace 525 with your node id and then add the javascript in the head section.

In template file add this code

```
<?php
function YOURTHEME-NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == 'CONTENT-TYPE')) {
        $vars['template_files'][] =  'page-node-add-CONTENT-TYPE';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create node--[nid].tpl.php file for specific node id and after that you can use your specific js file for specific node id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://drupal.org/project/scriptfield (shameless self promotion happening here).
This will let you do exactly what you need, on a per-node basis.

It's most useful if you need to do it to more than one node, since it will let you do it without creating one template per node id.